# HttpWebRequest in C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML code of a register page; http://jsbin.com/joxuwifo/1/edit

I somewhat understand how to use `HttpWebRequest` and the ability to enter information into specific fields programmatically; however, if you view the code above, an example for my upcoming question would be the textbox for "First Name".

Here is the code as is;

```
<div class="mrm lfloat _ohe">
    <div class="uiStickyPlaceholderInput uiStickyPlaceholderEmptyInput">
        <div class="placeholder" aria-hidden="true"></div>
        <input id="u_0_0" class="inputtext _58mg _5dba" type="text" aria-label="First Name" placeholder="" value="First Name" name="firstname" data-type="text"></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, the moment a user inputs a key from their keyboard to the textbox, immediately the div class name from "`uiStickyPlaceholderInput uiStickyPlaceholderEmptyInput`" goes to "`uiStickyPlaceholderInput`" with no other changes. If I were to enter the first name as "Smith", the actual word "Smith" is no where to be found in the HTML code.

The question is then, how can I programmatically enter information into each textbox field if the div classname auto changes and there is no actual value to put the text into?

I just need to automatically fill out each textbox and combobox and radiobutton.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you trying to programmatically fill out a form on a website that you do not control?

Comment: but don't you still have your control id's? like this one: <input id="u_0_0" ?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to programmatically fill out this form. The control id's are always the same, just I do not know how to do this. StaticVoid posted javascript, but I need it done in c#.

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the parent and drilldown from there:

```
$('.mrm.lfloat._ohe').children('div').children('input').val("Joe");
```

Had to add jQuery to make your fiddle work: http://jsbin.com/joxuwifo/4/edit

Comment: How would I accomplish this in C#?

Comment: Send this script from the server.

Comment: This isn't my server though, and I need this accomplished in c#.

Comment: Don't be this guy: http://serverfault.com/questions/31575/why-do-hackers-setup-bots-repeatedly-fill-out-web-forms

Nobody wants spam.

Comment: No it isn't for spam, it's rather for a personal project, testing out a few things.

Comment: Well if you can't access the server, then you cannot intercept/change the postback. I'm afraid you can only do this on your client.

Comment: That was the whole question though. I was asking how can I fill it out programmatically via c#?